# Change cursor when doing a mouse event

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How to change the cursor for a mouse event (right click for example) in Python with Tkinter ? When I press the right click, the cursor is changing but when I release it, the cursor doesn't change.

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.new_width=800
        self.new_height=600

        # Main window
        self.fen = Tk()
        self.fen.title("Image")

        canevas = Canvas(self.fen, bd=0) ## creation of the canvas
        canevas.config(bg="white")

        canevas.config(cursor="dotbox")

        canevas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True) ## I place the canvas with the .pack() method

        canevas.config(scrollregion=canevas.bbox("all"))

        w=canevas.winfo_width()
        h=canevas.winfo_height()

        self.fen.update()

        # This is what enables using the mouse:
        canevas.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", self.move_start)
        canevas.bind("<B3-Motion>", self.move_move)

        # start :
    def run(self):
        self.fen.mainloop()

    #move
    def move_start(self,event):
        self.canevas.config(cursor="fleur")

    def move_move(self,event):
        self.canevas.config(cursor="fleur")
```

Comment: your code isn't indented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind an event to the release of the button which changes the cursor back to `"dotbox"` using

```
canevas.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", self.move_stop)
```

Then you don't need the `<B3-Motion>` event, the cursor just stays `"fleur"` until you release the button

---

In the code you posted, you need to replace every mention of `canevas` to `self.canevas` to be able to reference to it in the `move_start` function (and any other class methods)