# Is there a way I can visually show where I clicked, using Python. Similar to pressing CTRL on Windows and seeing circles

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse

Currently my program will open an image, and with that image you can click anywhere on it and it'll return the pixel coordinates of where you clicked. And from those coordinates you are able to type some text and it'll display the edited image back to you. Yet, I was wondering if there was a way that would be visually helpful to the user showing them where they clicked. Here's my current code for opening the image and clicking on it to return the coordinates. I am using tkinter and I know I should've down from tkinter import *, but it's too late now :/.

```
    ### Function to open files ###
img_window = tkinter.PanedWindow(top, orient='vertical')
def file_opener():

    global actual_img
    global original_img

    top.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="*/Images/", title ="Select an Image", filetypes=((".png", "*.png"),(".jpg", "*.jpg")))

    original_img = Image.open(top.filename)

    #################### CLICK LOCATION OF WHERE YOU WANT TO ADD TEXT ####################

    event2canvas = lambda e, c: (c.canvasx(e.x), c.canvasy(e.y))

    imgApp = tkinter.Toplevel()

    # creating an img var of my original image
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original_img)

    #setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
    frame = tkinter.Frame(imgApp, bd=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    xscroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
    xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tkinter.E+tkinter.W)
    yscroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.S)
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set, width = img.width(), height = img.height())
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.S+tkinter.E+tkinter.W)
    xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    frame.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)

    # adding the image to canvas

    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(tkinter.ALL))

    #function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def returncoords(event):
        global cx, cy
        #outputting x and y coords to console
        cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
        return cx, cy


    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", returncoords)
    # canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", returncoords)

    imgApp.title("Please select an area on Image")
    imgApp.config(bg="red")
    imgApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Check this question and answer: [Change cursor when doing a mouse event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171800/change-cursor-when-doing-a-mouse-event)

Comment: thank you i got it! no special effect like the circles though, but still suffficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution: When the image gets opened up, it'll display the tcross cursor and when the user clicks it would change cursor's until the user releases.

```
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(cursor = "tcross")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(tkinter.ALL))

    # function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def returnCoords(event):
        global cx, cy
        # change the cursor when button is held / click so user knows they selected a coordinate
        canvas.config(cursor = "dotbox")
        cx, cy = event2canvas(event, canvas)
        return cx, cy

    def returnCursor(event):
        canvas.config(cursor = "arrow")
        time.sleep(.7)
        imgApp.destroy()

    # mouseclick event / release
    canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", returnCoords)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", returnCursor)
```